# Can a website hosted at a domain set cookies with domain value of its super super domain?

Tags: cookies

I have a website hosted at : `.xyz.abc.def.com`.

I want to set a cookie with domain value: `.def.com`.

I know it can be set from `.abc.def.com` but my confusion is if that can also be set from `.xyz.abc.def.com` or its just not possible?